# Export format from ArchiCAD import into Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, cad

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I would like to know in which format should I export a 3D work created in ArhiCAD in order to import it into Gazebo. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10997/export-format-from-archicad-import-into-gazebo/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-29**:
Here is a question about going from Solidworks files to URDF and STL files, it may be a good reference as you approach the problem http://answers.ros.org/question/794/converting-solidworks-stuff-to-urdf-stl-and

**Comment by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on 2011-08-26**:
No it doesnt have this feature, neither .dae, .stl.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-25**:
Can ArchiCAD export models in COLLADA (.dae) or STL format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, the only three formats supported by URDF/Gazebo/RViz are:

- .dae  (Collada)
- .mesh (Ogre)
- .stl

(also see [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/1144/query-on-urdfxacro-file#1904)). Perhaps ArchiCAD can export to a format that can be imported by another program which can export into one of those formats. Perhaps [this list](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/wiki/Liste_von_CAD-Programmen) of CAD programs and formats is of help (sorry, German link; the English Wikipedia page doesn't have ArchiCAD).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on 2011-09-20**:
I have obtained my file in .3ds, which i could load into MeshLab successfully, the further transformations failed because the loaded .stl and .dae files into RViz were proven to be with lacks. Just a few objects were visible from the created 3D environemnt. Although loading the .stl, .dae files works correctly in MeshLab. Anyone could help me by transforming my file using other 3D converter?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-29**:
I have found that you can use MeshLab (http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) to transfer between other intermediate formats, as well.  It may take a bit more work to clean up, but it generally does a pretty good job.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

making a quickly "googling" I found this:

> STL file format contains 3D model information, but ArchiCAD supports other 3D export file formats such as DWG, 3DS, C4D, U3D, etc., ArchiCAD models cannot be saved directly to .STL format. These 3D file formats need to be converted to STL file format using a converter application, for example the 3D Object Converter which can be found at [http://web.axelero.hu/karpo/.](http://web.axelero.hu/karpo/)

This converter is only available for windows. After the conversion you should be able to open the 3D model in Gazebo following the link posted for mjcarrol under you question (hsu answer - posted 29 apr)

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-20**:
can you post an example of mesh failing to load?  it would help if we could reproduce the error.

**Comment by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on 2011-09-20**:
Im getting .stl and .dae from MeshLab.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-20**:
@szokei:  what format are you getting out of MeshLab that's loading faultily in rviz?

**Comment by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on 2011-09-20**:
The 3D converter mentioned by you is not free. I've used the MeshLab but somewhere is leading to a faulty loading into RViz.